# Limit similar ids - results into sql

Tags: mysql, sql

2i've a table of repeated items, i got this table done from a left join.-
Lets say that this table alias is "piked"

```
ID     Product         PickedBY
1      Basket          Josh
1      Basket          Jessica
1      Basket          Josh
1      Basket          Mike
1      Basket          Mike
2      Seat            Alan
3      Computer        Jessica
4      Mouse           Josh
4      Mouse           Mike
4      Mouse           Jessica
```

I wish to limit the equal Ids to 2. how do i do it? so, if i list just ids result will look 1,1,2,3,4,4.

Thanks

Comment: please elaborate limit the equal Ids to 3

Comment: Why do you want to limit how often an id is repeated?

Comment: yes, the limit is two, was a typo, i edited it now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense to me which makes me wonder what you want to achieve with such a query but you can try to group the results:

```
select id, count(*)
from piked
group by id
```

That's not exactly what you asked but you can tell whether an id has duplicates by looking at the second column of the result. The result will be

```
1,5
2,1
3,1
4,3
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT ID, Product, PickedBy FROM (
SELECT
IF(@prev != q.ID, @rownum:=1, @rownum:=@rownum+1) as rownumber, @prev:=q.ID, q.*
FROM (
    SELECT
    ID, Product, PickedBy
    FROM piked
    , (SELECT @rownum:=0, @prev:=0) r
    ORDER BY ID
)q
)asdf
WHERE asdf.rownumber <= 2
```